# Bootstrap dropdowns not toggling with new rails layout

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have implemented a new rails layout and I'm unable to get the dropdowns from the navigation menu to work. The dropdown from the menu in the main page (a different layout) works fine. I do have jquery loaded but clearly something isn't loading in the correct order for this layout since it's not toggling.

The layout that works has this 'application.js':

```
//= require jquery
//= require popper
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree ./common
```

The layout that doesn't work has this 'stack.js'

```
//= require jquery
//= require popper
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require stack/vendors/vendors.min
//= require stack/vendors/charts/raphael-min
//= require stack/vendors/charts/morris.min
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/unslider-min
//= require stack/vendors/timeline/horizontal-timeline
//= require stack/core/app-menu
//= require stack/core/app
//= require stack/scripts/pages/dashboard-ecommerce
//= require_tree ./common
```

The files in common are page specific js files that are needed in both layouts.

Here's a snippet from a dropdown that works:

```
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
        <%= current_user.name %>
      </span>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <%= link_to( t(:profile), user_path(current_user), class:"dropdown-item") %>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <%= link_to("Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:"dropdown-item") %>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Here's a snippet from the new layout's navigation which doesn't work:

```
  <li class="dropdown dropdown-user nav-item"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-user-link" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="avatar avatar-online"><%= image_tag('stack/portrait/small/avatar-s-1.png')%><i></i></span><span class="user-name"><%= current_user.name %></span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ft-user"></i> Edit Profile</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ft-mail"></i> My Inbox</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="user-cards.html"><i class="ft-check-square"></i> Task</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ft-message-square"></i> Chats</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item") %>
    </div>
  </li>
```

applicacion.scss (drives layout that works only)

```
 @import "bootstrap";
```

stack.scss (drives layout whose dropdowns don't work):

```
///FILES IMPORTED FROM VENDOR.CSS///
@import 'bootstrap';

@import 'stack/fonts/feather/style';
@import 'stack/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome';
@import 'stack/fonts/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon';
@import 'stack/vendors/extensions/pace';
//// END FILES IMPORTED FROM VENDOR.CSS ///

@import 'stack/fonts/meteocons/style';
@import 'stack/vendors/extensions/unslider';
@import 'stack/vendors/charts/morris';

//FILES THAT WERE BEING IMPORTED BY APP.CSS

@import "stack/bootstrap-extended";
@import "stack/colors";
@import "stack/components";

////////

@import 'stack/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu';
@import 'stack/fonts/simple-line-icons/style';
@import 'stack/core/colors/palette-gradient';
@import 'stack/pages/timeline';
@import 'style';
```

I have tried changing the order in which the bootstrap js is loaded in stack.js but have had no luck. I've been trying to fix this for the last 2 days but I'm out of ideas. I'm using Rails 5.2. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the version of bootstrap you are using. If you are using bootstrap 4 remove all the `require` tags from the application.scss file.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4. However I do have bootstrap included in the application.scss (which drives one layout only) and it works fine. Updated above with scss details

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. Some of the JS in the template was loading jquery already, so by having it loaded in the layout.js files and then in the scripts (somehwere) as well, it was causing issues.